# Minecraft Java edition commands in Bedrock questions - "Fix my answer for me"

Tags: discussion, answers, minecraft, site-policies

Now, recently Minecraft bedrock and Java edition have grown very similar in most gameplay aspects, so in most gameplay questions I don't think it's a big deal if you are answering from a Java experience in a bedrock question (except for bugs obviously). However, they are extremely different in redstone and commands. No one asks questions about redstone anymore, especially in bedrock, so my problem lies in commands.

It's not uncommon at all, I've been on the verge of posting this for a while, that people answer bedrock questions with Java commands. What ends up happening is that a lot of the time they can be ported, and me or someone else has to fix them. (Sometimes they can't be ported at all.)

So, are we okay with leaving these answers if they are for the wrong version and have someone else clean them up? Or should they be not posted in the first place? People easily get confused by these answers if they have little command experience. Should whether they can be easily fixed or not influence whether it should be posted or not? Because these answers seem to have a "someone else will fix my answer for me" kind of thing.

The most common occurrences I see are:

- `distance=x..y` - Easily ported, but should be `rm=x,r=y`
- Incorrect `execute` syntax, sometimes able to be ported
- NBT, not portable (I think we can all agree these answers don't belong at all because they can't be used in any way)

along with many others. **So, should it be okay to post a slightly wrong answer if someone else can fix it?** These people sometimes say "this is the command for java" or "I don't know how bedrock works but...".

*P.S. - if you did this, I'm not saying you meant it like this or even did it consciously, but that's kind of what these answers imply.*

Comment: idrk if I used the word "port" right but u know what i mean

Comment: Related: [Questions where OP has mentioned he/she is using a specific platform: how to answer, how to tag and when to close as exact duplicate?](//meta.arqade.com/q/5488)

Comment: @Robotnik But in this case, Bedrock and Java have completely different commands at times. In that case, is it even needed to put a tag for the edition when asking about commands? I am literally just wondering what you think would be the best way to go about that.

Comment: @Potterton you're already pretty much required to put [tag:minecraft-java-edition] or [tag:minecraft-bedrock-edition] along with the [tag:minecraft-commands] tag anyway otherwise you will be asked to and receive no answers

Comment: @Penguin Fair enough! That logic does make sense.

Comment: @Potterton yep. If you [go here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-commands+-minecraft-java-edition+-minecraft-education-edition+-minecraft-bedrock-edition) pretty much all the questions have 1) people asking to specify the edition and 2) crappy answers, if any answers

Comment: @Penguin Wow. That is a long list. And lots of them are recent.

Comment: I cleaned that list up around the time of the [tag:minecraft] -> [tag:minecraft-java-edition] rename (adding an edition tag when there was some other indication of which edition was being played and flagging as unclear otherwise). It seems like more question have crept in, and I should probably do that again.

Comment: @ppery I've been trying to do that but for a lot of them you really just *can't tell,* and in that case it's better to just leave it unmarked if there are absolutely no hints

Comment: Also related, but from the question's perspective: [Can I use more than one Minecraft tag if my question applies to more than one edition of Minecraft?](//meta.arqade.com/a/15397/28182), [Is the same situation in two games too broad?](//meta.arqade.com/q/13128/28182)

Comment: @Potterton - Yep, tag with the game version you're playing - let the answerers decide if they want to answer for one or both versions, IMO

Comment: @Robotnik Thanks for the clarification. Minecraft is definitely an interesting case on Arqade!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, [a case I had](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/382501/in-a-given-location-how-can-i-give-a-player-some-item/382502#382502), which the answerer and I fixed. So it's actually better to fix the commands instead of deleting the answers. Just search around the web to find the correct ways then fix it.

If you don't have a specialty for Bedrock commands at all, then leave it alone. If the answers with wrong commands are there, just downvote it (just don't flag it) and let the answerer know what they've done wrong.

> **So, should it be okay to post a slightly wrong answer if someone else can fix it?**

No. Just as I said, leave the question alone and don't answer if you have no idea how Bedrock commands help. Still, if someone's being stubborn and still answers with a Java command, just downvote it, let them know what they did wrong, and help them translate it to the Bedrock version that the answerer's trying to replicate.