# How to tell if a Minecraft answer is valid for the tagged version of Minecraft?

Tags: discussion, minecraft

I saw [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/388043/163757) to a Minecraft Java edition question:

> You can use `testForBlock` command to search where the command block is
> placed (well, this command was then removed in Minecraft Java 1.13).
>
> The syntax of the above commands:
>
> ```
> /testForBlock <position: x y z> <tileName: Block> [dataValue: int]
> ```
>
> Or you could use `gamerule` command to disable command blocks in the map
> completely.
>
> Command:
>
> ```
> /gamerule commandBlocksEnabled false
> ```

To which the question asker [replied with a comment](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/388042/i-am-stuck-in-a-infinte-tp-loop-what-can-i-do#comment546906_388043) saying:

> I don't know where the command block is and *I don't play on bedrock*

As a person who has only primarily played vanilla Minecraft *Java Edition*, (well I played a good amount of Minecraft when it was on Xbox 360/One *before* it was replaced with *Bedrock edition*), and as a player who seldom used commands in any fashion, I for one cannot tell how the answer quoted above is specific to the Bedrock Edition of the game (as the comment from the OPer would suggest).

I've seen this happen a good amount - someone posts an answer valid to *X* version of the game when the question was about *Y* version and the answer isn't valid (i.e. a user asks a question about Java edition, but someone gives an answer that would only work in Bedrock).  This often clouds my ability to be able to improve posts, recommend/vote on deletions, etc. if I can't tell if the post in question is valid for the edition of Minecraft.

What are some give aways that could denote if an answer to a Minecraft question is specific to that version of the game?  Some things I thought of that could be give aways:

- Certain commands only found in certain versions of the game [(as someone else commented later)](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/388042/i-am-stuck-in-a-infinte-tp-loop-what-can-i-do#comment546931_388043).
- Certain features only available in certain versions of the game.
- Certain content only available in certain versions of the game.

But what commands/features/content are specific to which versions?

Comment: Why does this matter? We can't remove posts if they're for the wrong version anyway

Comment: @Penguin are we sure? Let pretend this was Stackoverflow, and someone asked a question about C#, and someone provided an answer that's in Python.  That wouldn't work, and should/would be flagged because its not an answer.  I feel this is the same type of situation no?  Regardless, I'd like to learn more at least for myself, because it could also improve my knowledge of game in general to potentially help others in the future.

Comment: @TimmyJimmy I'd like it to be that way but many said in [this question i made](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15612/258509) that we cant do that. If you look in the edit history I took out the word delete and changed the entire question to should it be okay to post bc of ppl saying we couldnt remove them. That might need to be another question on its own

Comment: @Penguin like my Stackoverflow example, I don't think that should be the way.  A question tagged with Bedrock shouldn't have answers that only work for Java, and vice versa. And they should not be edited (except by the original author) to work for the edition of the game the question was about.

Comment: @Penguin you're not arguing with me i agree with u it has no relevance, i just said that should be another question as currently most seem to agree u cant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, go visit the [wiki page](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Commands#List_of_commands) to see which commands are exclusive to which versions.

## Terminology used:

- **NBT data**: NBT stands for **N**amed **B**inary **T**ag, and it is used by Minecraft for the various files in which it saves data. The format is designed to store data in a tree structure made up of various tags.
  The syntax of NBT is similar to that of JSON, however keys are not enclosed in quotation marks.

Here are some other giveaways:

## Giveaways that an answer is for MCJE:

- The command includes NBT data and/or block states directly next to the entity/block ID.

  ```
  give @p diamond_sword{Test:1b}
  setblock ~ ~ ~ chest{Items:[...]}
  ```
- The command uses MCJE 1.13+ `/execute` syntax.

  ```
  execute as @a at @s run setblock ~ ~-1 ~ air
  ```
- The raw JSON text does *not* have `rawtext`:

  ```
  tellraw @p {"text":"hi."}
  ```

## Giveaways that an answer is for MCBE, or MCJE 1.12−:

- MCJE 1.13+ updated the location of NBT data within block and item IDs in commands, as you can see in the first bullet point in the above list. If the command includes JSON item data<sup>MCBE</sup> or NBT data<sup>MCJE 1.12−</sup>, *at the end of the command*, with two numbers in between, it's MCJE 1.12− or MCBE, depending on which is used:

  ```
  give @p dirt 1 0 {CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:stone"]}
  give @p dirt 1 0 {"minecraft:can_place_on":{"blocks":["stone"]}}
  ```
- The command uses old `/execute` syntax.

  ```
  execute @a ~ ~ ~ setblock ~ ~-1 ~ air
  ```
- The raw JSON text *does* have `rawtext`:

  ```
  tellraw @p {"rawtext":[{"text":"hi."}]}
  ```

I will update this answer with additional items.

Comment: I know Minecraft has an extensively written game wiki, but as a "Minecraft noob" I find it a little hard to use when it comes to looking up commands.

Comment: Also, cam you explain "The command includes JSON item dataMCBE or NBT dataMCJE 1.12−, with a count in between" some more?

Comment: Also, what are NBT tags? I see this term all over, but don't really know what they are.

Comment: @TimmyJim This answer is planned to be edited multiple times with more info, so thank you for asking those clarification questions. I'll push information about that on an edit as soon as I can. Thanks!