# Why is this question not about technical support for modded minecraft?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, minecraft, specific-question

The question [Recreate Item from NBT](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/395710/185203) was [reviewed as leave open by a moderator](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/close/316547) with no explanation, despite myself and three different close vote reviewers agreeing the question should be closed.

It seems clear to me that the question is off-topic as technical support for modded Minecraft, as [MegaLoot](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/megaloot) is a mod, and the question is about a `/give` command not interacting properly with that mod. That makes the question clearly ["diagnosis of [...] abnormal behavior caused by modding"](/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An oversight by me. I thought this was a question about why the NBT data wasn't working as expected (not reallizing a mod was in use). It's closed out now.

[My lack of Minecraft knowledge](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15937/163757) makes it sometimes hard to review close votes on Minecraft questions. This is made worse because Minecraft questions are one of, if not the most reviewed type of question. A lot of the time I rely on comments made by others for these types of questions to make an appropriate decision (I actually consider you as one of the best and more knowledgeable community members when it comes to reviewing these particular questions - you put some work in for closing Minecraft duplicates!).

This particular question this post is about I probably could have done better on though. A little bit of extra research would have probably led me to conclude it's about abnormal mod behavior.

<sub>Also, feel free to maybe improve my knowledge by posting an answer on my linked meta question :)</sub>

Comment: May I suggest not unilaterally reviewing questions as leave open in cases like these, and instead letting someone else handle the question? And I don't think I have anything more to add to the answer to the linked question.

Comment: I'd also vote to close that question, but as "needs details or clarity", not as off-topic. As per community consensus at the meta posts: [Minecraft crash questions should be made off-topic: yes/no?](//gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10390/4797), [Why just ban Minecraft modding tech support?](//gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10568/4797) and [What exactly is technical support?](//gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11015/4797) - only *crash* issues and other technical issues related to *running* modded Minecraft are off-topic. Outside of those, modded Minecraft issues are on-topic.

Comment: @pppery a lot of the time I do [skip these questions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/close/history?userId=163757&skipped=true) and let the community do its thing.

Answer (score 1):

I'd vote to close that question as "needs details or clarity", **not as off-topic**. We don't have a blanket ban policy on questions about modded Minecraft issues, technical support or otherwise.

As per community consensus at the meta posts: [Minecraft crash questions should be made off-topic: yes/no?](//gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10390/4797), [Why just ban Minecraft modding tech support?](//gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10568/4797), [What exactly is technical support?](//gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11015/4797), and [Update the off-topic reason for "Technical support for non-vanilla Minecraft" in the help-center](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13542/4797), only *crash* issues and other technical issues related to *running* modded Minecraft are off-topic.

Basically, if a Minecraft technical support question is one of these:

1.) I modded Minecraft and now it crashes.
2.) I modded Minecraft and now it won't run.

Then it's off-topic. Outside of those, modded Minecraft issues (technical or otherwise) are on-topic. A question about a command not interacting properly with a mod is not off-topic, since there's no crash and Minecraft is running without issues.